# I can't insert values into my salesfacts table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert values into my SalesFacts table. However, I get 0 rows affected. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the code? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

```
INSERT INTO 
  ClassicCars_Pte_LtdDW..SalesFacts(customerNumber, officeCode, productCode, employeeNumber, TimeKey, orderNumber, quantityOrdered, priceEach, buyPrice)
SELECT 
  cdim.customerNumber, dwoffice.officeCode, prod.productCode, em.employeeNumber, replace(CONVERT(DATE,o.OrderDate, 112),'-',''), od.orderNumber, od.quantityOrdered, od.priceEach, p.buyPrice
FROM
    ClassicCars_Pte_LtdOLTP..[Offices] office INNER JOIN ClassicCars_Pte_LtdOLTP..[Employees] e
    ON office.officeCode = e.officeCode

    INNER JOIN ClassicCars_Pte_LtdOLTP..[Customers] c
    ON e.employeeNumber = c.SalesrepEmployeeNumber

    INNER JOIN ClassicCars_Pte_LtdOLTP..[Orders] o
    ON c.customerNumber = o.customerNumber

    INNER JOIN ClassicCars_Pte_LtdOLTP..[OrderDetails] od 
    ON o.orderNumber = od.orderNumber

    INNER JOIN ClassicCars_Pte_LtdOLTP..[Products] p
    ON od.productCode = p.productCode

    INNER JOIN ClassicCars_Pte_LtdOLTP..[productLines] pro
    ON p.productLine = pro.productLine

    INNER JOIN ClassicCars_Pte_LtdDW..[OfficesDIM] dwoffice
    ON office.officeCode = dwoffice.officeCode

    INNER JOIN ClassicCars_Pte_LtdDW..[EmployeesDIM] em
    ON em.employeeNumber = e.employeeNumber

    INNER JOIN ClassicCars_Pte_LtdDW..[CustomersDIM] cdim
    ON c.customerNumber = cdim.customerNumber

    INNER JOIN ClassicCars_Pte_LtdDW..[ProductsDIM] prod
    ON prod.productCode = p.productCode
```

Comment: I do not Looks like mysql

Comment: Hi strawberry, I'm using SQL server.

Comment: If you run the SELECT part stand-alone, does it return anything? As a general advice, start with a one table SELECT, then build up your final statement in steps, by adding one table JOIN at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure of two things:
1) Run your select part of query and make sure if it returns rows.
2) Make Sure if your link servers are setup properly. Best by simple select something from them using link server names:

Select top 10 * from ClassicCars_Pte_LtdDW..SalesFacts
Select top 10 * from ClassicCars_Pte_LtdOLTP..[Offices]